# User accounts tab not showing in phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, plesk, privileges

I have been on cyberpanel for a few years and am making the switch over to Plesk. I have Plesk setup and working, I'm able to setup domains, database, etc.

I have a lot of wordpress sites and the way I migrate them is with Duplicator.  When I run the installer file to migrate the site on the new server (Plesk), I get a "the user XX is missing privileges on the database XX" error message.  It looks to be "Create & Alter Procedures" privileges are not granted.

Usually I would just go into phpmyadmin and grant user all privileges but when I go to phpmyadmin, there is not a User Account tab at the top like there usually is.

I made sure to be logged in as root, have restarted server, cleared cache, other stuff, and my last step was to reinstall Plesk on a different server and still same issue.

So I think my question is how can I view the user account tab in phpmyadmin so I can give the user all privileges but maybe there is something else I'm missing?

Comment: Only "admin" can edit database user accounts on Plesk. The subscription user cannot do that, neither does he need to. For the migration question: Did you create the database before migration on the target server? That will be necessary. Once the database exists and the username and user password for that database are correct, Duplicator can for sure import the database. 

StackOverflow is probably the wrong forum for the question. Maybe try talk.plesk.com or a Wordpress related forum.